# Execute command only once inside of infinite loop

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi wich i'm using to monitor an input from the GPIO ports, to do this i need to run an infinite loop.

When i receive a `LOW` in my input i want to execute a system command usint `subprocess.call`. The problem is that it executes this command for as long as the input is receiving `LOW` i have tried this to make it execute only once but i can't make it work.

```
while 1:
    if (GPIO.input(11) != GPIO.HIGH ):
         puerta_abierta = 1
         if(puerta_abierta == 1 ):
              call(["mpg123", "file.mp3"])
              puerta_abierta = 0
    else:
        puerta_abierta = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
puerta_abierta = 0
while 1:
    if (GPIO.input(11) != GPIO.HIGH ):
        puerta_abierta += 1
        if(puerta_abierta == 1 ):
            call(["mpg123", "file.mp3"])
    else:
        puerta_abierta = 0
```

Comment: This solution will call mpg123 every time the input goes HIGH and then LOW again because it resets puerta_abierta. Not sure if this is good or bad because its how the original code works, but violates the posters request that mpg123 only be called once.

Comment: Yes, it is. When I wrote the code, I knew it. And I think it is what the asker wants.

Comment: I like (and upvoted) your answer but wanted to toss in a caveat for the original poster in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you! I should write this in case of need.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
called = False

while True:
    if GPIO.input(11) != GPIO.HIGH:
        if not called:
            call(["mpg123", "file.mp3"])
            called = True
```

You could also break out of the loop, but that might not be what you intend to happen:

```
while True:
    if GPIO.input(11) != GPIO.HIGH:
        call(["mpg123", "file.mp3"])
        break
```

Comment: Thanks your fist option does work, i guess i didn't explained myself good enough. I want that after it has played it doesn't activate untill my input is `LOW` again